# Renault 1.4L 16v Oil Dipstick Location

Tags: oil, renault, clio

I have a 2002 Renault Clio Mk2 with a 1.4L 16v engine, which I have owned for 6 months.

There is a readout on the dash which indicates the oil level when you first turn on the ignition. My sensor is going faulty though - and I like to check my oil level manually anyway.

I cannot, for the life of me, find the dipstick on this car. I can see the filler cap, which does not have an integrated dipstick.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for that! I just had the same problem locating that dipstick, cursing those French always doing everything backwards and illogical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same car and I really hate having to check the oil level. The dipstick is on the front/underside of the engine close to the oil filter. It bright yellow, but since it's so well hidden it's easily missed.

Here's a photo for clarification:
[image: Clio 1.4 16v dipstick location]

Answer (score 3):

Checking several sights it should be on the front side of the engine. Near the middle of the block and under the fuel rail cover. Even in day light you may need a flashlight to locate it. It is by all accounts a royal pain to get at. Several queries were in regard to broken dip sticks. What this may mean is you can't find it because it has been broken off.

Comment: We must have been looking at the same sites, though the one I saw didn't specify which year I was looking at exactly and was showing a 1.2 and not a 1.4L engine (though they may be exactly the same).